# What is the handgun in the first Terminator (1984) movie poster?

Tags: the-terminator, the-terminator-series

Can this gun from *[The Terminator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Terminator)* be identified?

[image]

Comment: For questions about guns in movies, I'd recommend checking out the [Internet Movie Firearms Database](http://www.imfdb.org/wiki/Main_Page).

Comment: How is this off-topic?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[AMT Hardballer .45 Longslide with Primitive Laser Sight](http://www.range365.com/guns-terminator) - The Terminator (1984)

> The most visually striking firearm from the dark-toned The Terminator (1984) was the AMT Hardballer .45 Longslide featured at the beginning of the film and shown on the movie poster. The popular-at-the-time [1911](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M1911_pistol)-based pistol was fitted with a primitive laser sight made by a designer from the company that would become [SureFire](http://www.surefire.com/). It's the T-800's primary weapon until he loses it in the club Tech Noir after being shot by Kyle Reese's Ithaca 37 shotgun.

As a bonus we also know what's *The Terminator's first weapon* other than his bare hands of course.

[image]

Comment: "The .45 Hardballer with laser sighting."

Comment: Given its superior hand-eye coordination and everything, what could the T-800 possibly need laser sight for? I think that premise is almost as flawed as the humans-as-batteries thing in *The Matrix* ;) Oh wait, that's a question in its own right.

Comment: @Ghanima why take the sunglasses? Bad Ass. Why the laser sight? _Bad Ass._

Comment: @Brad, foresight! Can be used to cover up a damaged eye.

Comment: I wonder if the glasses can be identified? Brad?